# Boot Menu does not detect any media (USB, HDD, CD/DVD)

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I need some help here. I just installed the server version of Ubuntu on a 4-year-old Samsung laptop. I am quite familiar with desktop version of Ubuntu but not the server. I installed the server version of Ubuntu 16.04 on a Samsung laptop model # NP300E5X-A08AE with default installation as per the guideline and using UEFI booting system and removed the legacy BIOS.

After the installation was done, I found the Wireless, NIC, and USB do not work at all. I cannot connect to home network and internet. I cannot run live USB stick that I used to install the server version of Ubuntu 16.04. Then I removed the hard disk and created a startup disk on it from another laptop with the desktop version of Ubuntu 16.04.

However, After I put the hard disk back into Samsung laptop and power on the laptop, I found only Boot Menu as shown in the below photograph.

[image: Boot Menu of Ubuntu 16.04 Server]

All media (USB, HDD, CD/DVD) do not work at all.

Comment: If the computer is not detecting a properly-prepared bootable USB flash drive, then chances are its NVRAM has gotten messed up. Entering the firmware setup utility and resetting to the defaults may fix this problem. Of course, it's also possible that the boot medium was not properly prepared. You might want to try it on another EFI-based computer before you reset your firmware settings.

Comment: Kindly explain more about the firmware setup utility. I have tried several boot media and none of them detected. I got the same "boot menu" message and F2 or F4 does not function.

Comment: The firmware setup utility is built into the computer's firmware, and varies greatly from one computer to another. F2 and Del are two common keys used to access it, but some computers use other keys, and sometimes the key used is very finicky -- it must be hit at exactly the right moment, so it may take several attempts to get in. You should ask on a manufacturer forum if you need more help with this.

Comment: I don't think i still have this firmware setup utility in my laptop, since none of the F-keys are function. I think, the utility has been replaced during installation of ubuntu server version with UEFI firmware. I am stuck at the same "dead end" booting menu, no booting media detected; neither hard disk, nor cd/dvd drive nor usb.

Comment: The firmware setup utility is built into the firmware. Ubuntu cannot replace it unless Ubuntu replaces the firmware, and AFAIK Ubuntu does not do this during installation. Even if it did, the firmware installed would have to come from the computer's manufacturer. In sum, you're not looking at an Ubuntu bug; either you're not understanding how your firmware works or you're looking at a firmware bug. In either case, you should ask the manufacturer about it, or ask on a manufacturer-specific forum.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI requires the file /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi (64bit) or /EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi (32bit) in order to boot external media (this includes the CD/DVD).

Your system likely requires the file to be present before it will display the boot option for the device. There is a small possibility that it may not support external boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: Dear Ravery, does Live USB or CD/DVD of Ubuntu contents the file /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi or /bbotx32.efi in it? I have checked it in live USB and can not find that file? Where I can get the file and how to prepare a live USB with that file, so i can reinstall Desktop version of Ubuntu 16.04 on my Samsung Laptop?

Comment: Currently, I believe only the 64-bit version of ubuntu is EFI compliant. If ubuntu is the only operating system, there is no problem with enabling Legacy mode and installing in Legacy mode.

Comment: I found it in the live USB of Ubuntu-Server 16.04.03 LTS amd64 and try to boot from it. Unfortunately, My Laptop still not detect it, only the same display as before  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu2y5.jpg

Comment: Ravery wrote "Currently, I believe only the 64-bit version of ubuntu is EFI compliant. If ubuntu is the only operating system, there is no problem with enabling Legacy mode and installing in Legacy mode." I can not do any thing now, I do not have option to select the setup (F2) or Recovery (F4) except that display. How do I go back to legacy booting firmware or rewrite the UEFI firmware on it so it detect all media again.

Comment: is the USB formatted to FAT32?

Comment: I create the USB with Ubuntu-Desktop 16.04.  How do I check/confimr it if it is FAT32 or not?

Comment: I am going to create another Live USB with Dekstop version. What type of format for it? But there is no format option available in Startup Disk Creator. Should I format it before create alive USB?

Comment: start up disk is not needed. partition it GPT and format it FAT32. the extract iso to drive.